# PHP How hide the exceptions on production system

Tags: php, configuration, ini

I am searching for a solution to hide or disable the showing of exceptions on a production server.

In my configuration I have set

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = Off
```

but exceptions still appear.

Maybe it has something to do with the setting of `set_exception_handler()` in my app. I use a custom exception handler but I'm not sure if overrides the effect of `display_errors` and `error_reporting`.

How can I disable the exceptions for my production server?

Comment: This question has already been answered [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: This is the opposite of what I want. I want to hide the exceptions.

Comment: Making sure there are no errors in your code to begin with is where it starts, of course. Either way: `error_reporting = 0`, or `E_ERROR`(closest to 0) and display_errors = false, or if your PHP version permits it: `display_errors = stderr`, to send it to the stderr stream, instead of stdout.

Comment: Do you mean error/warning/notice messages, or do you mean exceptions? The two are very different things

Comment: Then you need to set an [exception handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php), and/or actually use try/catch blocks in your code

Comment: I did. I catch the exception and I don't want to print it anymore. I thought it may be from PHP configuration but I see that I need to implement something to avoid the printing.